# Easy way to share a drive with password protected directories?

Tags: storage-area-network, network-attached-storage, cloud-storage, network-storage, shared-storage

We have 50 computers that students share. Is there an easy way to have student folders on a single drive on the network where each student has a password? Students need to be able to go to any computer and access their password-protected directory.

All the computers are Windows 8, but I'd very much prefer not to have to use a Windows Server.

Right now we connect a USB drive to our router. Works great except the directories are not password-protected. We don't want students deleting other students' work.

I'm happy to use a cloud storage mechanism for this too.

Comment: Is there a difference between what you're describing and having centralized home directories? Do you have an existing username/password authentication source?

Comment: Our students do have usernames/passwords for our website, I could integrate with that. Or a separate username/password is fine too. Centralized home directories would be amazing, but would I need a windows server? I need this to be very simple.

Comment: Given that it sounds like your system is not centrally controlled or configured, home drives at the very least would require a Linux host running a samba file server, if not a windows domain controller. If neither of these are options appeal, you want a third party folder encryption tool (eg http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-encryption-utility.htm) or a cloud storage solution like Dropbox, Google drive etc. For 50 computers I think a Windows (or Samba) Domain Controller is well worth considering, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you'd prefer not to use Windows Server you might consider using Samba. It communicates as a Windows Server computer would, using the Microsoft Server Message Block (SMB) file sharing protocol (which is likely what your router is doing). You can easily configure it to require authentication. It can even emulate a Windows Domain Controller if you'd like to use functionality in Windows to allow users' settings to follow them between computers ("Roaming User Profiles") and such.

Comment: That sounds ideal. Is there a Samba device I can buy? Or do I have to setup a computer running a Samba server to run this?

Comment: Samba's a daemon that runs on a Unix server. It does pretty much the same as a standalone Windows box would.